# Doxygen is unable to add `#include<file.cuh>` in case of Files with extension *.cuh

Tags: doxygen

In case of *.cuh files, doxygen is not adding `#include<file.cuh>` to doc.

My file `sample.cuh` and content

```
/**
 * @file sample.cuh 
 *
 * @brief Class definition for smp::sample
 */

namespace smp {

/**
 * @brief A sample class
 *
 */
class  sample{
 public:
  /**
   * @brief Default constructor
   */
 sample();

};

}
```

With following option set in Doxyfile

`EXTENSION_MAPPING      = cu=C++ cuh=C++`

`FILE_PATTERNS          = *.cpp *.hpp *.h *.c *.cu *.cuh`

Comment: Which version of Doxygen? Are you using the doxy wizard? Where is the `#include<file.cuh>` placed as I don't see it in your example?

Comment: Doxygen version is  1.8.19, and when I meant `#include<file.cuh>`, I was expecting sample.cuh to be added to document as `#include<sample.cuh>` and point to it's source.

Comment: Something similar to this https://docs.rapids.ai/api/libcudf/nightly/classcudf_1_1column__view.html

Comment: So no doxywizard. I don't get " I was expecting sample.cuh to be added to document as #include<sample.cuh> and point to it's source", I see the documentation of the content of sample.cuh in the output when placing your code in a file sample.cuh and just the 2 lines with `EXTENSION_MAPPING` and `FILE_PATTERNS` in the Doxyfile.

Comment: Content of the sample.cuh will be visible, but I would like to see that this content belongs to sample.cuh. So, I wanted to see #include<sample.cuh> in documentation as well.

Comment: How would you like to see it, please show an image of the current situation and indicate where you would like to have the information. Isn't  the information at the bottom of the class page sufficient (it already says: "The documentation for this class was generated from the following file: sample.cuh").

Comment: I couldn't upload an image as I don't have enough reputation. But you can see an example in the below link. It mentions #include around top of the page https://docs.rapids.ai/api/libcudf/nightly/classcudf_1_1column__view.html. Look for #include<colum_view.hpp>.

Comment: After some searching I found the repository where the source code resides https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf I didn't really investigate yet but I think this has to do with the setting of `SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES=YES`, which will list the **included** files by a certain file.

Comment: I did some further tests and it was not the `SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES`. When I  name the file not `sample.cuh` but `sample.h` than the `include ...` is shown. Looking into the doxygen code we see that for a number of well known extension doxygen does a guess whether it is a header file or not. The `cuh` extension is in principle unknown to doxygen but by means of `EXTENSION_MAPPING` made known, though it is not known at that moment whether it is an include file or not (only the language is set), so doxygen cannot do anything with it in respect to the `include ...`

Comment: Thank you, even I was thinking it as SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES, but it wasn't and didn't venture much into doxygen code. Thank you for the explanation on doxygen side.